# How implement facebook comments in iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have an iPhone application that displays some content. I need to integrate facebook comments box for each article in my app. For web-site it's pretty simple but I can not find a way to implement this feature in iPhone app with facebook connect sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I am using setStatus and publishStatus method for this. It is working for me.